I have an Angular workspace with multiple projects. Why isn't my library building?
I have an Angular workspace with multiple projects, including a library with common functionality.
When I try to build my library e.g. with ng build my-lib, I get a long list of various errors from projects across the workspace.
Why might this be happening?

A possible cause of this behaviour is if you have imported something to your library from another one of the projects in your workspace.
This will not show as a type error, but will prevent your library from building successfully, and unfortunately there isn't a helpful error message to tell you why.
Libraries must be self-contained; all common code should be in the library of your workspace and imported by any other projects.
